# "pls-00201 identifier must be declared" in ASP.NET/C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure which I'd like to use in C#/.NET:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
procedure contact_return(
    v_urn IN VARCHAR2,
    p_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR )
AS
  sql_statement VARCHAR2(4000) := '        

  SELECT URN,
    FIRSTNAME,
    LASTNAME,
    TITLE,
    MOBILE,
    WORK,
    EMAIL
  FROM CONTACT
  WHERE urn = NVL(:1,v_contact_urn)';
BEGIN
  OPEN p_cursor FOR sql_statement USING v_urn;
```

Using this code, I get en error: **PLS-00201: identifier 'CONTACT_RETURN' must be declared**

```
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "contact_return";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("v_urn", OracleDbType.Int64).Value = null;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p_cursor", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

As far as I can see, I have declared the stored procedure ('contact_return') correctly, so cannot figure out why I'm getting this error.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

shouldn;t this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
procedure contact_return(
    v_urn IN VARCHAR2,
    p_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR )
AS
  sql_statement VARCHAR2(4000) := '        

  SELECT URN,
    FIRSTNAME,
    LASTNAME,
    TITLE,
    MOBILE,
    WORK,
    EMAIL
  FROM CONTACT
  WHERE urn = NVL(:1,v_contact_urn)';
BEGIN
  OPEN p_cursor FOR sql_statement USING v_urn;
```

be

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
procedure contact_return(
    v_urn IN VARCHAR2,
    p_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR )
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE sql_statement VARCHAR2(4000) := '';        

  SELECT URN,
    FIRSTNAME,
    LASTNAME,
    TITLE,
    MOBILE,
    WORK,
    EMAIL
  FROM CONTACT
  WHERE urn = NVL(:1,v_contact_urn)';

  OPEN p_cursor FOR sql_statement USING v_urn;

END;
```

Comment: Many thanks, I've just tried this (but removed the '; from the declare line, not sure if I should have) and unfortunately still get the same error

Comment: were you able to create the procedure? if not did you try show errors command to check the error ?

Comment: The procedure was created without any errors :) The only error I'm getting unfortunately is the C# one

Answer (score 1):

To call an Oracle store procedure containing `OUT` parameter of type `SYS_REFCURSOR` you need to use [ODP.NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085703.html).
The template solution will be like this:

```
using Oracle.DataAccess;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;

public DataTable Call_contact_return(string v_urn_value)
            {
                using (OracleConnection cn = new OracleConnection(DatabaseHelper.GetConnectionString()))
                {
                    OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter();
                    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
                    cmd.Connection = cn;
                    cmd.InitialLONGFetchSize = 1000;
                    cmd.CommandText = DatabaseHelper.GetDBOwner() + "contact_return";
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("v_urn", OracleDbType.Char).Value = v_urn_value;                    
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_cursor", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    return dt;
                }
            }
```